# How to show standard deviation using googleVis

Tags: r, googlevis

I am trying to show standard deviation using googleVis and was going to use [Intervals chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals). To my surprise I have not found it in googleVis 0.5.10.

Is there a way to still do Intervals chart in googleVis? Or what other way to show standard deviation would you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intervals are not supported, but I can show standard deviation by using annotations capabilities of google charts, which googleVis do support. More information here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html